# Shell: baixar e descompactar em uma linha

Tags: linux, shell

Eu tentei utilizar wget com o tar da seguinte forma

```
wget -qO- [url] | tar xvf
```

mas não consigo o efeito esperado. Existem outras formas para fazer isso?

Comment: `wget` escreve na saída padrão com esses parâmetros? Se sim, o erro está em fornecer um arquivo sem nome para o `tar`. Experimente remover a flag `f` ou colocar `/dev/stdin` como argumento de `f`

Comment: Verdade. Não percebi. @JeffersonQuesado, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu consegui utilizando

```
wget -qO- [link] | tar xz
```

O parâmetro z foi inserido por ser um arquivo tar.gz.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar

```
wget [link] && tar xvzf [nome_arquivo].tar.gz && rm [nome_arquivo].tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Que tal:

```
$ wget -O - https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.7.tar.gz | tar xvzf -
```